# Configuring Xdebug with docker compose

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, xdebug

I'm trying to configure a WordPress development environment with docker-compose and Xdebug but I can't get the debugger to work with a simple break point on `info.php` file after starting my debugging session in VSCode.

Here are my configs:

dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

RUN pecl install xdebug
```

php.ini

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./wp:/var/www/html
      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      PHP_EXTENSION_DEBUG: 1
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  wp: {}
```

.vscode/launch.json

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html":"${workspaceFolder}/wp"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lT75qjcnco&t=423s&ab_channel=NoFluffDigital) with the exact same steps and still not able to do step debugging.

Comment: *"xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal xdebug.remote_port=9003"* What is your Xdebug version? Quite likely it's Xdebug v3. If I'm correct then the thing is -- your Xdebug config (php.ini) is for Xdebug v2. But v3 has changed the parameter names & values. Your current config does almost nothing in v3. **Go through https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide and adjust your config to use Xdebug v3 parameters.** P.S. May also check https://matthewsetter.com/setup-step-debugging-php-xdebug3-docker/ or some other article

Comment: You can check your current / live Xdebug config from `xdebug_info()` output (that's for Xdebug v3) -- so you can see if the values used are correct with what you put into the config. For old Xdebug v2 that would be the dedicated Xdebug section of the `phpinfo()` output.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem as you

For my case, put those config in the `ini` is not enough, I need to put the xdebug config into docker-compose.yml, it looks like:

```
services:
  Wordpress:
    ...
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_port=9003 remote_enable=1
```

xdebug 2.7.0, php 7.0, visual code 1.72.1 (php debug ext v1.29.0)